# mysql: left join but select one particular item from the joined table

Tags: sql, select, mysql, left-join

I need to select a row only from two corresponding tables, for instance,

member table,

```
member_id   member_name
1           xxx
2           yyy
```

profile_picture table

```
image_id   member_id   image_approved
1          1           no
2          1           no
3          1           yes
```

I want to select one row from member table each time and one approved image from profile_picture. I am using left join but it doesn't work right as it duplicates the selected member when this member has more than 1 uploaded images. the tricky part is I want to select the image which has been approved only and it is always one picture will be approved.

```
SELECT *
    FROM member 

    LEFT JOIN profile_picture 
    ON profile_picture.member_id = member.member_id

    WHERE member.member_id = '1'
```

I would like to get this as a output,

```
member_id   member_name image_id image_approved
1           xxx         3        yes
```

is it possible?

thanks.

**edit:**

thanks guys for the suggestions. many of you have suggested using **AND** - for instance, **AND profile_picture.image_approved = 'yes'**

it works only when the image is present. but if the image is absent, there is nothing in the output even though it should output like this below if the image is absent.

```
member_id   member_name image_id image_approved
1           xxx         null      null
```

thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
  *
from
  member m
  left join profile_picture p on p.member_id = m.member_id
where
  m.member_id = '1'
  and (p.image_approved is null or p.image_approved = 'yes')
```

`image_approved` isn't part of the join condition, so I don't put that in the `join` clause.  It's rather part of the row selection condition, so it goes in `where`.  Thinking about what you want, you either want nothing in `profile_picture`, or the approved row.  So, conditions.

Comment: `m` and `p` are table alises.  The `as` keyword is optional and implied, so `member` is aliased to `m` and `profile_picture` is aliased to `p`

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `image_approved`condition to you query gives you the output you need for given inputs.

```
SELECT *
    FROM member 

    LEFT OUTER JOIN profile_picture 
    ON profile_picture.member_id = member.member_id

    WHERE member.member_id = '1'
          AND image_approved = 'yes'
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM member  
    LEFT JOIN profile_picture  
    ON profile_picture.member_id = member.member_id 
    WHERE member.member_id = '1' 
    AND profile_picture.image_approved = 'yes'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a `LEFT JOIN` where an `INNER JOIN` is appropriate.  You need a column on `profile_picture`, right?  It seems like all you need is an additional `WHERE` condition:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   member
   JOIN profile_picture USING (member_id)
WHERE
   member_id = 1
   AND image_approved = 'yes'
```

Is there a possibility to have more than one column on the right table and you only want to get one?  Do you want the last approved image?  Add these:

```
GROUP BY
   member_id
ORDER BY
   image_id
```

Comment: Result will not include members with 0 images.

Comment: From his question it doesn't sound like that's the case, but that is easy to resolve.  Just change the JOIN to a LEFT JOIN and put the image_approved condition in the ON clause (currently a USING clause)

Answer (score 0):

Either accommodate the NULLs in the WHERE clause as Donnie recommended or use a table expression to restrict your 2nd table like this:

```
Select member.member_id, member_name, image_id, image_approved
From member LEFT Outer Join
     ( Select image_id, member_id, image_approved
       From profile_picture
       Where image_approved = 'yes' ) Images
          on Images.member_id = member.member_id
```